# How can I set default value in MySQL view?

Tags: mysql, view, default-value

I wrote the following code to create view in MySQL:

```
CREATE VIEW anag AS  SELECT f.NAME AS NAME ,f.id AS id,s.map_level AS map_level FROM server s ,functionalci f WHERE s.id = f.id
union
SELECT f.NAME AS NAME ,f.id AS id,ws.map_level AS map_level FROM webserver ws ,functionalci f WHERE ws.id = f.id
```

I want to add new attribute in the view as "type_id", and I want to set the default value is 0;
note: neither functional table, server table nor webserver table doesn't have "type_id" attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `type_id` with value 0 in your query.

```
CREATE VIEW anag AS  SELECT f.NAME AS NAME ,f.id AS id,s.map_level AS map_level, 0 as type_id FROM server s ,functionalci f WHERE s.id = f.id
union
SELECT f.NAME AS NAME ,f.id AS id,ws.map_level AS map_level, 0 as type_id FROM webserver ws ,functionalci f WHERE ws.id = f.id
```